# Multiple provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, upgrade, profiles

We have an enterprise app that is installed on approximately 2500 devices. We are in the final stages of producing a version 2 upgrade. Our enterprise distribution certificate is expiring soon so we have created a new distribution certificate and distribution provisioning profile. So far, upgrading the app results in a second provisioning profile being installed.

Why doesn't the app overwrite the current profile instead of installing a second one? Everything about the profiles (old and new) is the same except for the uuid.

Our concern is that having more than one profile on the device with the same name will cause problems. Our hope is that someone can illuminate this behavior for us.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is not of a problem. The device may have the same (named) provisioning profile installed multiple times. It is all about the ID that has to match with the one the app is built against -> no worries.

Comment: But the two profiles I'm referring to are functionally identical except that the second one was built with a renewed distribution certificate. The problem we are afraid of is that the first profile (older one) will start alerting the user that it is about to expire even though a newer profile exists that is not within the two month expiration alerting period resulting in user confusion and potential help desk activity.